# MariaDB and PHP-FPM high cpu load

Tags: mysql, php-fpm, mariadb

we have a dedicated server running only 1 domain (Wordpress) with 500 users per minute and have very often timeouts.
Server Specs:
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 v3 @ 3.50GHz (12 core(s))
64GB RAM
2 x 200GB SSD Raid 0
OS: Debian 9.6 , Plesk Onyx 17.8, MariaDB 10, PHP-FPM 7.2

We just tuned some DB settings but still have the timeouts/breaks.
MariaDB CPU Usage is 200% , PHP-FPM 50% CPU per Instance
Can anyone help ?

Here is the my.cnf
key_buffer_size     = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam_recover_options  = BACKUP
max_connections        = 200
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10

#query_cache_limit  = 1M
#query_cache_size        = 16M
skip-name-resolve   = 1
table_cache     = 8192
table_definition_cache  = 8192
table_open_cache    = 16384
sort_buffer_size    = 16M
query_cache_limit   = 24M
query_cache_size    = 256M
join_buffer_size    = 10M
tmp_table_size      = 512M
max_heap_table_size = 512M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 24G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 8
innodb_flush_method = O_DSYNC
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0
innodb_lru_scan_depth = 256

Comment: Do you have any caching solutions in your WordPress?

Comment: no w3 and/or other caching plugins installed

Comment: That should be the very first thing you do, then!

Answer (score 0):

Some of your tuning options are dangerous. Most are horrendously counterproductive. Leave the following and remove the rest:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=24G
skip_name_resolve=1
```

Then set:

```
slow_log=1
long_query_time=0
```

Capture a few hours of slow log and put it through mysqldumpslow or pt-query-digest, and fix the queries that are eating most of your CPU, through better indexing or rewiring them more efficiently.

Comment: slow log activated but nothing in there, but meanwhile 5 times timeout

Comment: FPM CPU usage 80% per instance, MySQL CPU usage 210% , memory usage mysql 5% and memory usage fpm is below 1%

Comment: Did you reduce the long_query_time to 0?

Comment: yes is set to 0

Comment: Do you have log_output set to file or table?

Comment: nothing set there using default

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_output';`

Comment: ok with query_time = 0 there is now a lot of output, changing to query_time = 1 no output is there

Comment: As I said, run with query time of 0. Capture a few hour of log. Put it through pt-query-digest. See what queries are consuming most CPU time and do something about it.

Answer (score 0):

For more detailed analysis, see:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning

Off hand:  `query_cache_size = 256M` is too high, leading to CPU activity to keep it purged.  In *most* cases, it is best to turn off the query cache.

WordPress?  Here's another tip, but it involves changing tables there:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

My suggestions on the setting up the slowlog:

```
log_output = FILE
slow_query_log = ON
slow_query_log_file = (fullpath to some file)
long_query_time = 1
log_slow_admin_statements = ON
log_queries_not_using_indexes = OFF
```

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog